# Подписка на событие с передачей параметров

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте,у меня есть 3 объекта

```
  public  Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
  public Rectangle square = new Rectangle();
  public Ellipse circ = new Ellipse();
```

я хочу чтобы они двигались.Создал функцию

```
 private void TimerTickForRect(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(rect, Canvas.GetLeft(rect) + 1);
        }
```

И добавил таймер

```
  timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50); // update 20 times/second
            timer.Tick += TimerTickForRect;
            timer.Start();
```

Вопрос.Как мне не плодить функции  в стиле

```
private void TimerTickForRect(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(rect, Canvas.GetLeft(rect) + 1);
        }
        private void TimerTickForSquare(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(square, Canvas.GetLeft(square) + 1);
        }
        private void TimerTickForCircle(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(circ, Canvas.GetLeft(circ) + 1);
        }
```

а просто сделать универсальную функцию?

Comment: Лучше двигать на разное расстояние, но с одним таймером.

Comment: Canvas.SetLeft((UIElement)source, Canvas.GetLeft((UIElement)source) + 1);
 сделал так.Но выбивает  System.InvalidCastException

Comment: Вообще-то sender - это создатель события, здесь это объект типа Timer (а именно тот самый timer)

Comment: Можно побольше кода увидеть? Весь, желательно

Comment: @АлексейСаровский, не подумал.

Comment: @bohdansavych, а зачем каждому элементу создавать свой таймер - почему бы их все в одном не двигать?

Comment: Нужно,чтобы была возможность двигать элементы отдельно.И с разной периодичностю.

Comment: @bohdansavych, лучше двигать на разное расстояние, но с одним таймером.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо.Буду знать.Каждый таймер отдельный поток верно?

Comment: @bohdansavych, не уверен, что там внутри таймеров. Но обновление экрана в одном таймере более логично, чем куча разрозненных изменений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, вы хотите просто лямбду?

```
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50); // update 20 times/second
timer.Tick += (o, args) => Canvas.SetLeft(rect, Canvas.GetLeft(rect) + 1);
timer.Start();
```

Отдельная функция `TimerTickForRect` оказывается не нужна.

---

Если функция разрастётся, то возможно вы хотите такое:

```
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50); // update 20 times/second
timer.Tick += (o, args) => MoveRight(rect); // именно rect!
timer.Start();

void MoveRight(UIElement e)
{
    Canvas.SetLeft(e, Canvas.GetLeft(e) + 1);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам,но,наверное ,лямбда мне не подойдет,так как функция потом у меня будет розрастаться .Я вот бы хотел узнать как вместо object source передать мой Объект .Или как в функции иметь доступ к source.Пробовал явно привести-не видит функций.

Comment: @bohdansavych: а разве source не есть `rect` в вашем случае?

Comment: Когда я  привожу к типу выбивает invalidCastExp

Comment: @bohdansavych: Тогда попробуйте так, как в обновлении. Лямбды позволяют добавить в контекст что угодно.

Comment: спасибо !Но можете обяснить  что делает эта строчка  timer.Tick += (o, args) => MoveRight(rect); // именно rect!
подписывает на ивент анонимный делегат с моей функ.?

Comment: @bohdansavych: Именно так, анонимный делегат. Поскольку в этой точке мы знаем `rect`, мы можем поместить его в closure. Таким образом получается как бы адаптер сигнатуры ивента к нужной вам сигнатуре.